# What value should be passed in universalLink?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, wechat

When I try to integrate WeChat Login in my iOS app using swift language, I am getting an error message on the simulator screen.

[image]

I am following integration steps from [this link](http://www.kekearif.com/how-to-implement-ios-wechat-login/).

I also have a query about the universal link which is needed for register app in AppDelegate like:

```
WXApi.registerApp("-------I HAVE IT-----", universalLink: "")
```

what should I pass in universalLink?

Comment: [ryanomor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15303109) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66631110) saying "Here's Apple's documentation on creating a Universal Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html"

Comment: Did you get to know what to pass in that parameter in the end?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/oplatform/Mobile_App/Access_Guide/iOS.html

You should configure your own universal link to access to your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to configure it? I am using an older Wechat version without that parameter and the english documentation on the link you provided is not updated

Comment: I don't remember exactly what to do.
Translate the page with google translate and you will find your answer ;)